# Probability of picking strawberry ice cream for first time on the sixth selection from five flavors?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

An ice cream store has five flavors. If we pick flavors successively selected at random, what is the probability that the flavor strawberry will be selected for the first time on the sixth selection?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: The same as the probability that you pick something other than strawberry five times in a row and that you picked strawberry immediately after that.

Answer (score 0):

If the strawberry flavor was chosen for the first time on the sixth iteration this means, we did not choose it on previous $5$ iterations.
The probability of not to choose the strawberry flavor at random pick is 
$$
\frac{4}{5},
$$
i.e. $4$ possibilities out of $5$ are not strawberry.
We did this $5$ times in succession, thus the probability of not to choose the strawberry flavor at any of $5$ trials is
$$
\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^5.
$$

At the sixth time we succeeded to choose the strawberry flavor.
The probability of this event was
$$
\frac{1}{5},
$$
i.e. one possibility out of $5$.

Now collect everything together.
The probability of 5 "misses" and then a "hit" is the multiple
$$
\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^5\frac{1}{5} = \frac{4^5}{5^6} \approx 6.5\%
$$

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! You rock!